# Simple SQL for matching MONTH

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve all sales within a given month, but only in this year.

```
   MONTH(app_date) WHERE MONTH('2014-07-01')
```

Return all sales from July, for the last 3 years.
How do I just match this month, for this year??

Comment: What`s your database?

Comment: `WHERE MONTH('2014-07-01')` is not a valid condition. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For july use

```
WHERE MONTH(app_date) = 7 AND YEAR(app_date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE MONTH(app_date) = MONTH('2014-07-01')
AND YEAR(app_date) = YEAR ('2014-07-01')
```